# freeradius + ldap + google-authenticator

Tags: active-directory, ldap, radius, one-time-password, google-auth-library

I want to implement login to my vpn service with password + google_otp. freeradius as auth server and ldap as backend_database.

I have completed the following work：

1. enable pam Authentication Module in /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
2. add a line "DEFAULT Auth-Type := PAM" to /etc/raddb/users
3. enable ldap module and add ldap site to freeradis, I confirm that raidus use ldap database is working properly.
4. Overwrite the contents of /etc/pam.d/radiusd

```
auth requisite pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/tmp/.google_authenticator user=root forward_pass
auth required pam_unix.so use_first_pass
```

run test cmd:(testpa is my password,271082 is otp)

```
radtest perlingzhao testpa271082 localhost 1812 testing123
```

radius log:

```
(0)     [pap] = noop
(0)   } # authorize = updated
(0) Found Auth-Type = pam
(0) # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authenticate {
(0) pam: Using pamauth string "radiusd" for pam.conf lookup
(0) pam: ERROR: pam_authenticate failed: User not known to the underlying authentication module
(0)     [pam] = reject
(0)   } # authenticate = reject
(0) Failed to authenticate the user
(0) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
```

log in /var/log/secure:

```
radiusd(pam_google_authenticator)[11728]: Accepted google_authenticator for perlingzhao
pam_unix(radiusd:auth): check pass; user unknown
pam_unix(radiusd:auth): authentication failure; logname=root uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=
```

I know this is because there is no local user, user info is in ldap.

anyone can help me , tell me how to config can solve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest using a PHP script for OTP validation instead of PAM modules, it does not create real local users but only verifies the TOTP itself. PHP has LDAP functions as well.

```
authorize{
    update control { 
        Auth-Type := `/usr/bin/php -f /etc/raddb/yourscript.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' '%{Client-IP-Address}'`
    }
```

There is a commercial [product](https://www.token2.com/?content=totpradius) that appears to fully meet your requirements.

P.S. I am affiliated with #1